# replace missing values in cases with at least one other value and drop cases where all values are missing

Tags: statistics, stata

I would like to replace missing values (the respondent did not answer the question) in Stata for those cases where the respondent answered at least one other question and drop those cases where all values are missing. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that you have an identifier `id` and questions `q1 q2 q3`. All are missing if and only

```
missing(q1) + missing(q2) + missing(q3) == 3
```

or the result of

```
egen nmissing = rowmiss(q1 q2 q3)
```

is 3. Use a similar recipe for other numbers and names of similar variables and then apply `drop`.

Otherwise replacing a missing value usually means applying `replace` according to your desired protocol, which you do not specify.

In Stata what you call cases are customarily called *observations*.